# How can I redirect http traffic to an absolute link path with iptables

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I'm trying to redirect a host to a specific link on my network when they try to browse through http. The ip of the host I'm trying to redirect is `192.168.2.19` and my web-server is on 192.168.2.15:6969/test.js. When I redirect the user I can only get him to 192.168.2.15:6969 and not the relative path. I tried specifying in the iptables command but it did not work. Here's what I did,

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000


iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.19 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT 
--to-destination 192.168.2.15:3000/test.js
```

Any help or suggestions will be higly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `iptables` alone.

You could use `iptables` for the network redirect, and then a webserver vHost  to redirect the URL from `192.168.2.19/*` to `192.168.2.15:6969/test.js/*` (or whatever).